# Does Attribute Routing with Conventional mapped routes make sense

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We have many web api solution with 2 projects. One project sets up the web api config stuff and the other project contains the controllers.

Each web api config is setup with this:

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

As we use Route/Prefix-Attributes on every controller/action I asked myself does the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute method call still take effect?

Actually as soon as I annotate a Route Attribute on the controller at least I overwrite the convention behavior of the web api. Thus the method call is obsolete.

Is that correct? Or is there still something to consider, because I want to remove this method call in every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention-based route will still be applied. Your attribute-based routes will take precedence (because they are configured first) but if an action method has both matching attribute routes *and* conventional routes, *both* routes will map to the action in question.

If you want to use exclusively attribute-based routing, removing the convention-based route mapping is probably a wise move in order to prevent unexpected behaviour (i.e. exposing actions under unintended routes).

Of course, you will want to be sure that you're not inadvertently relying on convention-based routing anywhere first!